# How get all album images from my own facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android application that gets all photo albums from my Facebook page and show them. I want to do this without Facebook logging.

I tried using Facebook graph API USER TOKEN, but it limits API calls to 200 per hour. But my application will be used by large crowd.

I also tried using Facebook graph API APP TOKEN, but it asks for app review. For app review it needs to supply a screen-cast. How I create a screen-cast before creating the app or can you suggest a another way to do this

Comment: "used by large crowd" - NEVER EVER hit the API for every user. you need to cache results. either way, you should use an extended page token for your page.

Comment: @luschn Can you suggest me a way to cache result

Comment: mysql, mongodb, ... whatever you prefer

Comment: If you want to use a page token or your app token, then this doesn’t belong onto the client side in the first place. You need to involve a server-side component and make the requests from there, otherwise you’d possibly be exposing those tokens to everyone.